# Cannot debug Android from Eclipse

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I have a problem debugging apps on my Samsung Galaxy S3, (GTI9300, I believe this is also known as the international version) from Eclipse.

The thing is, debugging actually worked for a time and then it just stopped working. I've tried quite a few things to make it work again. I'll describe my whole experience briefly, to keep you from suggesting things I've already tried, and save us all some time.

When I first got my phone, debugging didn't work. When I plugged in my phone, the system detected it, and I could use it almost like a storage drive (using Media Transfer Protocol or some such thing) But when I started Eclipse and tried to debug, the debugger didn't see the phone. 
I googled some, learned that I had to install some specific driver. I honestly don't remember which driver it was, but I believe it was an official one (from Samsung's website). Once I installed this driver, Windows would no longer detect my phone as a storage device. But the debugger did see it, and I was able to debug a few simple apps that I'd made. I could easily live with this tradeoff.

Then I got busy with other stuff and set Android development aside. I came back to it this weekend - after 2 or 3 months - only to find that it no longer works. No matter what I do, the debugger does not detect my phone (Windows still won't detect it either).
I tried all the first aid solutions like restarting Eclipse, rebooting my computer and rebooting the phone. Just for the sake of completeness, I do have usb debugging enabled on my phone. 
The only major change of the whole setup that I can think of is that my phone's OS has recently updated. I don't know the exact version it was before, right now it's Android version 4.1.2 (Kernel version 3.0.31-1160235, if this is useful to anyone). I tried plugging the phone into other computers, it gets recognized as a media/storage phone. I can't install the Android development tools and try debugging on any of these computers - I'm stuck with the one I've got.

I've tried reinstalling the usb drivers for my phone. It didn't help. In desperation (and against my better judgement) I tried installing Samsung's software, first AllShare Control, and eventually Kies. None of it helped. When I run Kies, it gives me the option of connecting through USB or via WiFi. However it won't detect my phone when I plug it in. When I click "Troubleshoot connection" (or some such thing, unfortunately Kies decided to use my native language instead of English) it starts reinstalling the USB driver. This process takes quite a while, and fixes nothing.

I'm basically out of ideas, I don't know what to try next. Any help would be appreciated.